# HTTPS request causes Uncaught exception Caller Tenant ID cannot be -1

Tags: iterator, wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

WSO2 REST proxy service called via HTTP has no problems, but calling via HTTPS sometimes throws exception:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2016-06-15 16:52:59,693] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Caller Tenant ID cannot be -1
at org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.Util.checkAccess(Util.java:36) org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CarbonCacheManager.getCache(CarbonCacheManager.java:111)
org.wso2.carbon.security.pox.POXSecurityHandler.getPOXCache(POXSecurityHandler.java:414)at org.wso2.carbon.security.pox.POXSecurityHandler.invoke(POXSecurityHandler.java:153)
```

Proxy uses the iterator and aggregate mediators.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4645). It has been fixed but as of now, there hasn't been a release since the fix.

Therefore you can get a clone of the repo with latest changes and build it manually to solve the issue.